# Symfony2 on NGINX, php file get downloaded

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I have a basic symfony2 app,  when I try to reach the host I get a download instead of the execution of the PHP code.

This is the vhost configuration:

```html
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name sandobox.dev www.sandbox.dev;
 root /var/www/sandbox/web;
 
 rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
 
 try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
 
        location @rewriteapp {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
        }
 
        # Deny all . files
        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
        }
 
        location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_index app.php;
                send_timeout 1800;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
  #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
 }
 
        # Statics
        location /(bundles|media) {
                access_log off;
                expires 30d;
 
                # Font files
                #if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
                #       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                #}
 
                try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
        }
}
```

This is my nginx.conf file

```html
user nginx;
worker_processes 4;
worker_cpu_affinity 01 10;
worker_rlimit_nofile 1024;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {

    # max_clients = worker_processes * worker_connections
    worker_connections 1024;

}

# Global environment variables


http {

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush off;

    keepalive_timeout 65;
    keepalive_requests 100;
    send_timeout 60;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # Logging of trivial open() errors resulting in 404 to error log
    log_not_found off;

    # Send back the version in the error pages?
    server_tokens off;

    # Files to serve when directories are requested
    index  index.php index.htm index.htm;

    # Automatic directory indexing
    autoindex off;

    # Defaults to on, but it's a problem for trailing slash redirections
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    # Increase the maximum length of a virtual host entry
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    # Compression
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 0;
    gzip_types text/plain;

    # Include separately managed configuration file(s)
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}

~
~
~
~
```

Thanks in advance for any hint

Comment: Is there a php worker listening on port `:9001`?

Comment: Check out your php-fpm settings (the 'listen' parameter); make sure you have php-fpm service runned. And I think you don't need 'fastcgi_index app.php' string.